# Aim Assist in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

Well, I'm working on something, but I'm stuck right now. as Title says it's about an "aim assist" for a shooting game. I move my camera using pitch-yaw updated every frame. like this:

```
void Update()
{
    float pitch -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensivity;
    float yaw += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensivity;
    Vector2 rot = new Vector2(pitch, yaw);
    cam.tranform.eulerAngles = rot;
}
```

And my AimAssit() method look like this:

```
void AimAssist(float weaponRange)
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.SphereCast(cam.transform.position, radiusDetection, cam.transform.forward, out hit, weaponRange, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Shootable"))
    {
        GameObject aimTo = hit.transform.gameObject;
        Vector3 direction = aimTo.transform.position - cam.transform.position;
        cam.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(cam.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), .1f);
    }
}
```

So, The problem is they don't work together, it's a mess. I know one of these work with degrees and the other one use angles, it's confusing. In other words, what I need is <s>snap the crosshair in the head</s> and still move fine with mouse. Thanks in advance.

BTW, I made this, but it was useless:

```
 Vector2 aim = new Vector2(Quaternion.LookRotation(direction).eulerAngles.x, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction).eulerAngles.y);
 CamTransform().eulerAngles = currentRotation + (Vector2)aim;
```

To be clear "direction" is the same from AimAssist().

Comment: What do you mean by "_snap the crosshair in the head_"? If you are literal about it, you can just put a crosshair using `aimTo.transform.position`, that is the location of the matched target, and remove the logic that moves the camera in the `AimAssist` method

Comment: Ok, it was more than exaggerated, ignore that. Either way I wrote as minimal as I can. the complete code is massive. but if someone resolve my question watching the minimum part, it's enough to me.

Comment: Again, what kind of effect are you trying to achieve? Both classes keep trying to control your camera, you should define a criteria for who will be able to do so and when. E.g. "the mouse controls the camera, but when there is no mouse movement, the camera is pulled to look into the aim by itself"...

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues both classes work hand in hand, whatever the input is, "mouse", "Joystick", etc. is going to move my camera using "transform.eulerAngles" and, AimAssist is going to help to find the position of my target when i'm aiming close to him, in other words "inside the range (SphereCast)". What I wrote above is what i tought it could work, if someone suggest me something better it would be perfect to me.The idea is... If i aim to the target and he is inside the range of my "aim assit", aim assit is going to find him, it's just a help to aim better and faster.

Comment: So, again... Remove from aim assist all the logic that moves the camera and keep only the logic that tracks and find aims. The position of the targets can be accessed through the transform components of the found gameObjects

Comment: I did it, before you suggest it even, it just doesn't work.

Comment: well, you will have to be specific about what _" they don't work together, it's a mess"_ or _"it just doesn't work"_ mean...